# is it ok to sing mantras?

Tags: mantras

I really dig this Ganesh mantra sung by Suresh Wadkar. I use it during aerobics and meditation and just doing housework. But I have been told that this is a bad practice. Is there canon support for this claim or is it a respect issue? or is there some other issue I am missing?

It's not really a personal question ... I'd like to know in general if this is a bad practice.

Answer (score 4):

It is not Ok to sing mantras.

[Here is an article](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Devi_Mahatmyam) about the Devi Mahatyam (Chandi Patha) on Hindupedia.com that discusses about the various rules and regulations of reciting it.

> The full reading can also be done over seven days viz one chapter on
>   the first day, next two chapters on the second day, next one chapter
>   on the third day, next four chapters on the fourth day, next two
>   chapters on the fifth day, next one chapter on the sixth day and last
>   two chapters on the seventh day.
>
> It is important to know that daily the parayana should start with the
>   Trayanga Mantra, text of Devi Mahatmya followed by the chanting of
>   Devi Suktham. It is also essential not to stop in between while
>   reading a chapter. If for some reason, it is stopped, the entire
>   chapter should be read again.
>
> It has also been told that
>
> **Geethi**, seegri, sirakhambhi, hyakurvano vinasyathi,
>  Thatho jnathwaiva sampannamidham prabhyathe budhai||
>
> **Those who sing it**, those who read it fast, those who read with shaking of their head, those who read from the text in their own
>   handwriting, those who read without understanding the import and those
>   who read in a very feeble tone, **do not get the benefit of reading a
>   work**. It has also been told that any book, which has less than one
>   thousand slokas should be recited from memory to get full benefit.
>   Those who cannot should keep the book on a stand so that it does not
>   rest on the ground.

Note that the Devi Mahatyam is not only comprised of slokas but they (the slokas) are also mantras. It can be shown, for example, that there are exactly 700 mantras in the stotra (and hence the name Saptasati) but if one counts the number of slokas in it then that will be found to be as less than 700.

Also, in the quote above, the relevant portion is the only the verse (Geethi seegri ...) which says that one must not sing it.

So, generally, mantras must not be sung.

I am not sure about the scriptural source of the verse cited but it appears to me that it's from a Siksha Grantha. And, Siksha (phonetics) is one of the six [Vedangas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedanga).

Comment: do they mention why anywhere?

Comment: No I don't know. Probably the reason is not mentioned. Basically mantras are not songs and hence they mustn't be sung.@KauvaAatma